# Gradle: Both Java and Android Subprojects on Same Project

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, gradle

TL;DR: IS the only way to develop both pure Java and Android applications, is on completely different Gradle projects?

I am developing a project which includes an Android application and a Java backend (along with some other common APIs).
As an IDE I am using IntelliJ Idea.
I would like to have a single Gradle project (which will be opened on a single Idea instance), that contains all the applications as subprojects.

My problem is that in order to allow the Android plugin, I need to set it in the `buildScript` section in `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
}
```

This forces the android plugin in the entire Gradle build process, and causes errors on the pure Java subprojects (they are automatically set to be built with the Android SDK instead of the Java SDK).

A workaround I have thought of is creating two separate projects (one for Android and one for Java), export the common JARs into a local Maven repository and import it from there into the Android project.

Is there a better solution that will allow me to have all the code base in the same place?

Comment: You can create both android and java modules in one single project using Android Studio. for android gradle use `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` and for java gradle use `apply plugin: 'java'`

Comment: This wouldn't work: I am getting a message: `Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found.` The plugin will only be recognized if I will add the `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3` into class path dependency inside the buildGradle section.

Comment: yes. should add it in project level gradle file

Comment: This is what I am trying to avoid: Setting the classpath this way, forces all the projects to use the Android plugin, instead of Java plugin.

Comment: Then I guess its better if you use 2 different projects for it. Find some other way for linking them with each other. e.g. Maven repo with jar

Comment: @GuyYafe it is possible with a single project, see my answer.

Comment: Did you manage to find a working solution?

Comment: I found a partial solution: When working with such "hybris" environment, Idea gets confused because it tries enforcing Android environment on all projects. This isn't actually affect the build itself, but causes error messages on all pur Java projects.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is possible: you just need to **move the buildscript** declaration from the project to the android module.

The PROJECT `build.gradle` may look like this:

```
buildscript {
    // nothing for the project
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter() // you could also move this to each module
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And the Android MODULE `build.gradle` may look like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
// other pluguins

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
        // other dependencies for the build (apt, retrolambda...)
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.android.app"
        // additional config...
    }
}

dependencies {
    // your app dependencies here
}
```

Other modules, such as backend or web, may declare their own buildscripts with their own pluguins, repositories and dependencies.

Comment: This answer is missing the settings.gradle file, but it is the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Each project has it's own buildscript classpath

root/build.gradle

```
project(':java-project') {
    apply plugin: 'java'
}

project(':andoid-project') {
    buildscript {
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        }
    }
    apply plugin: 'android'
}
```

Comment: Maybe I am doing something wrong, but this still forces the Android plugin classpath to all projects. Here is how the `root/build.gradle` looks like:

  allprojects{
    group 'com.navnplay'
    apply plugin: 'idea'
    repositories {
      mavenCentral()
    }
  }

`project(':navnplay-app') {
  buildscript {
    repositories {
      jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    }
  }
}`

Comment: Hard to tell... but I think you're setting the `buildscript` in an `allprojects` closure which ... as the name suggests... affects all projects

Comment: The `buildscript` is definitely in the project section and not in the `allprojects` section.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an android user but perhaps you need to tweak the [JavaCompile](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.html) tasks on the java only projects such that the compiler is forked and uses a different `javac`

```
allprojects {
    if (plugins.hasPlugin('java') && !plugins.hasPlugin('android')) {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            options.fork = true
            options.forkOptions.executable = '/path/to/javac'
        }
    }
}
```